# Venue Time Series Data Retrieval

Tags: foursquare

In order to access the time series data for a venue does it need to be managed by me, or should I be able to access the data with an access token?

Answer (score 0):

Only the manager of a venue can access the venue's time series / demographic stats. Apps that are authorized by the venue manager can make requests on the manager's behalf (using their auth token)